# Magento 1.x Custom Module - get wrong Frontend Url

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1, url

I have Mage 1.9 with my custom module installed. I have checked that the function

```
Mage::getUrl('mymodule/api/users/1');
```

return wrong url with admin path. We also use a custom path for the admin area.
This is my config.xml

```
     <admin>
            <routers>
                <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <Mymodule_Mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mymodule_Mymodule_Adminhtml</Mymodule_Mymodule>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </adminhtml>

            </routers>
        </admin>
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mymodule_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
```

Now, calling `Mage::getUrl('mymodule/api/users/1')` from admin area return this url:

```
https://website.com/index.php/admin/mymodule/api/users/
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve but you should look at the `getUrl` method definition : `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:1001`.

The first param of this method should be the 'route' : i.e `ỳour_router_name/your_controller_name/your_action_name`. And if you want to pass param, it should be as an array in the second param of the `getUrl` method.

Something like : `Mage::getUrl('mymodule/api/your_action_name', array('users'=>1))`.